# How can I make Google BigQuery understand a date format like 04.01.2019 07:06:48.607?

Tags: formatting, google-bigquery, format, looker-studio

I am using Google BigQuery to analyze a CSV-file in my Cloud Storage of 130 MB and 21 Mio. search strings entered of a webshop. When trying to evaluate this data with Google Data Studio I get no data when adding a "time dimension" with the format 04.01.2019 07:06:48.607.

The file is too big to change every field manually.

I currently use as type STRING and as mode NULLABLE because the field "timestamp" will result in an error otherwise.

Eventually I would wish to have all the data in this table be filterable by periods so I may see the trends of the search queries entered.

Thanks for your help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lT2TR.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this at the query level by using [`PARSE_TIMESTAMP`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#supported-format-elements-for-timestamp):

```
WITH
  data AS (SELECT 1 AS col_1,"04.01.2019 07:06:48.607" AS timestamp,"foo" AS col_3)

SELECT
  * REPLACE(PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%E*S",ts) AS timestamp)
FROM
  data
```

I'm making the assumption that the values above are month *then* day—if not, you'll need to swap the first part of the pattern to `%d.%m`. Also, I'm using BigQuery's `SELECT * REPLACE()` syntax to overwrite the original value of your column with the formatted version in the results (which also has the upside of preserving the original field order). It's a great feature, but could just as easily incorporate that same function call into your existing query.

Where you do this for your report is up to you; you could use a Custom Query data source in Data Studio to modify with a query like above, add a view in BigQuery with this logic and use that as your source (but note that views negatively impact caching for Data Studio), or materialize the table manually or using a scheduled query.

When you run this on the table, you'll get an error if any of the values don't match this pattern. If you need to make adjustments, reference the full list of [supported format elements for timestamps](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#supported-format-elements-for-timestamp). You can also call the function with the [`SAFE.`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/syntax#safe_prefix) prefix (i.e. `SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP()` if you would rather get a `NULL` value when a timestamp can't be parsed.

(Note that you can also use [`PARSE_DATETIME`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#parse_datetime) with the same format string if that data type is more appropriate for your use case.)

---

**UPDATE:** It looks like you have multiple problems here.

1. You aren't skipping the header row when you add the CSV as a table, which is causing the headers to also be a row in the data (which doesn't conform to the schema). Ideally, you can do this with the "header rows to skip" option on the Create Table screen (you'll need to expand the "Advanced options"):
   [image: Google BigQuery "Create Table" dialog with the "Header rows to skip" option highlighted]

Once that's fixed, the query above should work for you—just replace the table name with your real table (you could paste it into the Custom Query box when you set up the connection to BigQuery). If for some reason you can't change the import settings, you could eliminate the header rows with `WHERE` by adding this to the query:

```
WHERE
  id != "id"
```

If you aren't comfortable doing this in BigQuery, you could also technically do it in Data Studio by creating a new calculated field with this formula:

```
TODATE(timestamp,"%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%E*S","%Y%m%d")
```

In order for this to all work, all of the rows need to have the same format (e.g. getting rid of the duplicate headers).

If it were me, I would do this in BigQuery, either by using a Custom Query connection, or by running an `UPDATE` on the table to replace the column with the correctly-typed value.

Answer (score 0):

The following rebuilds the string into the proper format for conversion to timestamp.

```
with example as (
  select '04.01.2019 07:06:48.607' as my_datestring
),
components as (
  select 
    my_datestring,
    substr(my_datestring,1,2) as m,
    substr(my_datestring,4,2) as d,
    substr(my_datestring,7,4) as yyyy,
    substr(my_datestring,12,2) as hr,
    substr(my_datestring,15,2) as min,
    substr(my_datestring,18,2) as sec,
    substr(my_datestring,21,3) as milli
  from example
),
prep as (
  select 
    my_datestring, 
    concat(yyyy,'-',m,'-',d,' ',hr,':',min,':',sec,'.',milli,'000 UTC') as fixed_datestring
  from components
)
select my_datestring, fixed_datestring, cast(fixed_datestring as timestamp) as my_timestamp
from prep
```

`*` Assumes the date is April 1 (if January 4, you will need to switch `m` and `d` in the `components` CTE.
`**` Also assumes a UTC timestamp, you might require additional adjustment depending if your source data is tied to a specific timezone or if your final output requires a specific timezone.
`***` There is likely a more clever way of splitting/reformatting the string

Comment: While string splitting is effective for unknown types, `PARSE_TIMESTAMP` and `PARSE_DATETIME` provide much more efficient control for known types (see my answer for details). Also, the "clever" way you're looking at for at parsing strings would be a regular expression: `REGEXP_REPLACE("04.01.2019 07:06:48.607",r"^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+) (\d+:\d+:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$","\\3-\\1-\\2 \\4")`. While that output could be passed directly to `TIMESTAMP()`, it's still better to use battle-tested timestamp parsing libraries (which will also be more performant).

Comment: Hey thank you so much! this looks like a way that really might help me out with this one. :) I get an error when adding it after SELECT  FROM `project.dataset.spreadsheet` LIMIT 1000 

How may I add your code to my current query so I may export it to data studio? :)

Comment: I would create a view that does this transformation (and any others) in the BQ interface, then have Data Studio query the view.  *Not a user of Data Studio, so I assume it can query views.

Comment: @NesElm You'll find my answer below much easier to use as a Custom Query in your Data Studio data source. Just grab the `SELECT` portion, replace `data` with your project.dataset.table name, and replace the `ts` column with your actual column name (both places). Since it only replaces that one field, it means you don't have to worry about modifying any of the field definitions in your data source.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. :D I still could not figure out the right wording:

SELECT
  * REPLACE(PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%E*S",timestamp) AS timestamp)
FROM
data

>>"timestamp" is my actual column name and the data i already added. Then i get the "Failed to parse input string "timestamp" error.