# Date format in Google Cloud Storage changes date to YYYY-DD-MM format

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I upload data to Google Cloud Storage from CSV. The data in CSV is in dd/mm/yyyy format (in my example it is 05/09/2022 or 5th of September) and according to the metadata settings, I can see the default date is mm/dd/yyyy and it reads the date as 9th of May. How can I solve this issue and make GCP to read the date in dd/mm/yyyy format?   [image]

Comment: How does your issue relate to BigQuery?

Comment: the custom time field does not represent the date format of the underlying data.  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#custom-time

Comment: load the csv with all date columns as string. Then parse them manually as date in a query.

Comment: @MFR have you tried the above suggestions

Comment: Hi sorry for getting back earlier. Parsing manually with a query is possible. However, I wanted to know if there is any way to change the format in Google cloud storage?

Comment: @MFR I think you can do this at the query level only

Comment: I have provided an answer below. so that others could spot the workaround easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this at the query level only. There is no way to change the format directly.

Also as mentioned above in comments,  the custom time field does not represent the date format of the underlying data. You can refer to  this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#custom-time).

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements),format string represents the textual form of date and time and contains separate format elements that are applied left-to-right. Load the csv with all date columns as string, and parse them manually as date in a query.

Additionally you can check this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56970044/how-can-i-make-google-bigquery-understand-a-date-format-like-04-01-2019-070648) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59548775/bigquery-fails-on-parsing-dates-in-m-d-yyyy-format-from-csv-file)